# Nested intervals in $\mathbb R$ containing exactly one point

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, real-numbers

This is Exercise 16 from page 102 of *Analysis I* by Amann and Escher. I appreciate any feedback on the rigor and correctness of my solution.

**Exercise:**

> [image]

**My attempt:**

(a) It is clear that there can be at most one element in the intersection, because if there were two distinct elements $x, y$ in the intersection, they would be some positive distance $\epsilon$ apart, and the fact that all intervals beyond some $n \in \mathbb N$ are shorter than $\epsilon$ means that the intersection cannot contain both $x$ and $y$.

Thus we have established that the intersection of all the intervals is either empty or it contains one point. We reason that the intersection cannot be empty as follows. The only way $\bigcap_n I_n$ can be empty is if at least one of the intervals $I_n$ is empty, or if at least two of the intervals $I_j, I_k$ are disjoint. I think it is clear that neither of these are possible, so we conclude that the intersection is not empty and therefore contains one unique point.

(b) Here I use something that is not discussed in the text to this point, and which I hope is correct: a number is irrational if and only if it can be written as an infinitely long non-repeating decimal.

If $x \in \mathbb Q$, then simply let $I_n = [ x, x ]$ for all $n \in N$. These are degenerate intervals but they satisfy criteria (i) and (ii).

If $x \in \mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Q$, then $x$ is irrational and we build the intervals $I_n$ using decimal approximations to $x$. Hopefully the following example makes the algorithm clear:

\begin{align*}
I_1 &= [3, 4]\\
I_2 &= [3.1, 3.2]\\
I_3 &= [3.14, 3.15]\\
I_4 &= [3.141, 3.142]\\
I_5 &= [3.1415, 3.1416]\\
&\vdots .
\end{align*}

I appreciate any feedback.

Comment: For (a) note that infinite intersection of non-empty sets $S_1\supset S_2\supset S_3\supset\dots$ may be empty. E.g. you can take $S_n=(0,1/n)$. In (a) it is very important that the intervals are closed.

Comment: @SMM Thank you. Looks like I have to go back to the drawing board for that one.

Comment: Wait, the question says the intervals have to be closed. So then I'm home free? Or maybe I just need a bit more justification...

Comment: @Novice Yes, but you have not used that argument in your proof, please find a way to weave it in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say:

> The only way that $\bigcap_nI_n$ can be empty is if at least one of the intervals $I_n$ is empty, or if at least two of the intervals $I_j$, $I_k$ are disjoint.

This requires proof, because it is **not** true for open intervals, as you can see by taking $I_n=\left(0,\frac1{2^n}\right)$ for $n\in\Bbb N$. I suggest writing $I_n=[a_n,b_n]$ and considering $\sup_na_n$ (or $\inf_nb_n$).

What you’re using in (b) is true, but you really don’t need it: you can construct the intervals $I_n$ recursively, and it’s good practice to do so, because such constructions are quite common. To get started, there are rationals $p_0$ and $q_0$ such that

$$x-1<p_0<x<q_0<x+1\,.$$

Given $p_n<x<q_n$ for some $n\in\Bbb N$, there are rationals $p_{n+1}$ and $q_{n+1}$ such that

$$\max\left\{p_n,x-\frac1{2^{n+1}}\right\}<p_{n+1}<x<q_{n+1}<\min\left\{q_n,x+\frac1{2^{n+1}}\right\}\,.$$

Let $I_n=[p_n,q_n]$, and show that these intervals form a decreasing nest whose intersection is $\{x\}$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. For (a), if I understand correctly, you are suggesting that I show that $\sup_n a_n \in I_n$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$? For (b) you are repeatedly using the density of the rationals, right? I need to think about this more.

Comment: @Novice: Correct on both counts.